# Inbound eMail Handler - monitor incoming mails

Tags: apex-email-service, emailmessage, inboundservices

I add a inbound email handler into my org to add a new record in a custom object (bt).

Sometime the mails are not processed and I don't know why. Is there a way to check the incoming mails in Salesforce?

can I enter a line in the code where the process should begin and end? Because sometimes is some text before or after the relevant points.

```
global class btFromEmail implements Messaging.InboundEmailHandler {
    
global Messaging.InboundEmailResult handleInboundEmail(Messaging.InboundEmail email, Messaging.InboundEnvelope envelope) {
    Messaging.InboundEmailResult result = new Messaging.InboundEmailResult();
    bt__c C = new bt__c(); 
        if(email.plainTextBody != Null && email.plainTextBody != '') {
            String[] emailBodyRows = email.plainTextBody.split('\n');
            for (String bodyRow:emailBodyRows) {
                String[] rowContents = bodyRow.split(':');
                String label = rowContents[0].trim();
                String value = rowContents[1].trim();
                switch on label {
                    when 'Firstname' {
                        c.Firstname__c = value;
                    }
                    when 'Lastname' {
                        c.Lastname__c = value;
                    }                 
                    when 'Birthdate' {
                         c.Birthdate__c = date.valueOf(value);
                    }                   
                    when 'Phone' {  
                        c.Phone_private__c = value;
                    }              
                    when 'Email' {        
                        c.E_mail_private__c = value;                                        
                    }                            
                }            
            }
        }
      insert c;             
      return result;
  }
    
}
```

Comment: is this an issue in production or can you reproduce the issue in sandbox?  If the issue is sporadic, you might need to log to an sobject every incoming inbound email and the resulting `bt__c` inserted.  Be sure you have apex exception emails configured correctly so any exceptions get reported to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I put all mails into a note, than I have an overview of mailtraffic.